# Ruby on Rails - NoMethodError in Signups#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error while trying to pass "Innovation Cloud" lesson on Codecademy. I couldn't find any solution on Stack Overlow or GitHub.

```
NoMethodError in Signups#new
Showing /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_innovation-cloud/innovation-cloud/app/views/signups/new.html.erb where line #40 raised:

undefined method `email' for #<Signup id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Important fragments of code:

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/thanks" => "pages#thanks"
  resources :signups
  root "signups#new"
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :signup %><br> 
      <%= f.text_area :email %> 
    </div>

    <div class="actions"> 
        <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
         </div> 
         <% end %>
```

**db/migration**

```
class CreateSignups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :signups do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**signups_controller.rb**

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  private
  def signup_params
    params.require(:signup).permit(:email)
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)
    if @signup.save
      redirect_to '/thanks'
    else
      render 'new'
  end 
  end

end
```

Comment: Use <%= f.text_field :email %>  rather then <%= f.text_area :email %>

Comment: The `create` method in your `signups_controller.rb` file shouldn't be private.

Comment: Is it private? Isn't only `signup_params` private? There's no `private` keyword over `create`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Any method below `private` is private.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. So that's why moving `create` to the top helped.

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, some code tried to call a method `email` on an instance of `Signup`. Its not clear what line of code corresponds to the line number 40, but my guess is its the following:

```
<%= f.text_area :email %>
```

Anytime you build a form with an ActiveRecord instance (as you do with `form_for(@signup)`), any input generated will expect an attribute on your model with the same name. In this case, its looking for an attribute named `email` on `@signup`. It does this so that the field can be populated with the current value of that attribute on the model. While this might seem unnecessary for a `#new` action, it makes perfect sense for an `#edit` action, and allows you to reuse the same form code for both.

Since I'm guessing you'd like to store the email along with the signup, you need to add the attributes to the `Signup` model with a migration like so:

```
rails generate migration AddEmailToSignup email:string
rake db:migrate
```